# Eliminar espacios en <ul> dentro de una tabla

Tags: table, li, posicionamiento

no sé muy bien cómo formular esta pregunta por ello no he logrado encontrar información. Expongo el problema:

Tengo una tabla simple con 4 td con sus títulos y luego, abajo, otros 4 td con unas listas con diferentes puntos, el primero td tiene 4 li, el segundo tiene 3 li el tercero tiene 7 li y el cuarto td tiene 13 li.

Parece que tengan una especie de "vertical-align:middle" y me genera unos espacios blancos en las listas que tienen menos li. La pregunta es ¿Cómo hago que TODOS los UL se posicionen al principio de arriba y eliminar los espacios en blanco?

¿se ha entendido?

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Titulo1</td><td>Titulo2</td><td>Titulo3</td><td>Titulo4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                        <li>Ejemplo</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ponerlos al inicio con [`vertical-align: top;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). Usa un selector diferente para especificar las celdas que te interesen.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Titulo1</td><td>Titulo2</td><td>Titulo3</td><td>Titulo4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
                <li>Ejemplo</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```